# User friendly URL for one folder in website in php

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting

I have a website  `mysite.com`,This website is already developed.

I have an other folder `Partner` where i have another website(mysite.com/Partner/) which is already developed and working.

I want to create a third website `mysite.com/usa/`. Now i do not want to disturb the old .htaccess file and old setting.

I want to have user friendly url in usa website only.

Note:My question is not `How to create friendly URL in php?` ,

Is it possible? If yes then how?

Comment: Be more specific what you exactly want. PHP is not the solution, it will be a combination of techniques like modifying the htaccess to catch the url and some PHP code to 'understand' the request.

Comment: You can redirect with .htaccess, this might help http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, people want to have different settings for each of their folders --- that's why we have `.htaccess`

You can create another `.htaccess` in `mysite.com/usa/` and have a separated configuration.

As for the user-friendly URL, you'll need to have mod_rewrite installed in Apache too.

Comment: Can i create two .htaccess files?will it effect old .htaccess?

Comment: @user3244721 By saying old .htaccess, did you mean the .htaccess in mysite.com/ ?

Comment: Then `.htaccess` in `mysite.com/usa/` wouldn't affect anything in `mysite.com`. However, since /usa/ has it's own `.htaccess`, it wouldn't listen to `.htaccess` from `mysite.com` anymore. If you still need those settings from `.htaccess` in `mysite.com/`, you can  copy & paste them in your newly created `.htaccess`